# Matlab random elements from array

Tags: matlab

I would like to pick two different random elements from given array with their positions. Similar like with datasample, but with datasample there is a possibility of picking the same element twice. 
I could use while loop or similar, but I suppose there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried.

Comment: See: [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) and [mcve]

Comment: To avoid replacement use `datasample(data, 2, 'Replace', false)`; or `randsample(data, 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have a matrix  A:n by m, you can choose two elements at random as following,

```
A=[2 7 8;5 4 6;8 3 11];%given array
[n m]=size(A);
x=2;%two different random elements 
i=randperm(n,x)%row index for x elements
j=randperm(m,x)%column index for x elements
A(i(1),j(1)) %First random element
A(i(2),j(2)) %Second random element
```

If you try this you could get something like,

```
i =

 2     3
```

j =

```
 2     1
```

ans =

```
 4
```

ans =

```
 8
```

the code can be further simplified but just wanted to make it clear. Please let me know if you have any additional questions or require further clarification.

Comment: That works great, thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help